# Select same column name from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT posts.id, posts.date, posts.title, comments.post, comments.id, comments.date FROM posts, comments WHERE posts.id = comments.post")       
or die(mysql_error());  

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result3 )) {
    echo $row2['title'];
}
```

The problem is with the posts.id , posts.date and comments.id , comments.date . How can I get out id, date for both tables `$row2['....];` I tried `$row2['posts.id'];` but it didn't work!

Comment: mysql_fetch_array also returns the id's of the fields. See my answer.

Comment: You have 3 types of fetch: array (name and id), assoc (name), row (id). The id's are in the order of your SELECT. If you select * they come in the order of the table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Name the column in your query (this is called an column alias) like this:

```
SELECT 
    posts.id as postsID, 
    posts.date, 
    posts.title, 
    comments.post, 
    comments.id as CommentsID, 
    comments.date 
FROM 
    jaut_posts, 
    f1_comments 
WHERE 
    jaut_posts.id = f1_comments.post
```

Then you can use:

```
echo $row2['postsID'];
echo $row2['commentsID'];
```

Edit:

You may also benefit from [this question I wrote and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) which discusses many common SQL queries and requests.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `as` in your query, some thing like

```
select post.id as PostId, comment.id as CommentId
```

and then :

```
row["PostId"]
row["CommentId"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result3 )) {
  $post_id = $row2[0];
  $posts_date = $row2[1];
  $posts_title = $row2[2];
  $comments_post = $row2[3];
  $comments_id = $row2[4];
  $comments_date = $row2[5];
}
```

Comment: This works, but do you think that this is the most intuitive way of doing this?

Comment: It's the simplest. This is a basic question so it is best to give a basic answer.

Comment: Perhaps it is just me, but I always found that named fields were *much* easier to use rather than a numeric array in the order that the columns are specified in the `select` statement. They also won't cause problems if the SQL is changed as long as they are still selected.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.date, posts.title, comments.post, comments.id, comments.date
```

into

```
SELECT posts.id AS postsid, posts.date, posts.title, comments.post, comments.id AS commentsid, comments.date
```

then you can use `$row2['postsid'];` and `$row2['commentsid'];`

Answer (score 0):

Create alias:

```
$sql = 'SELECT posts.id AS post_id, comments.id AS comment_id ...';

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

echo $row['post_id'];
echo $row['comment_id'];
```

or, alternatively, you can access it by indexes (since you're using `mysql_fetch_array` anyway)

```
echo $row[0]; // posts.id
```

Comment: @tntu did that, what are you trying to say?